# How to search commit body in gitui

Tags: git, fuzzy-search

I'm a big fan of gitui. However when go into the log section and type <kbd>f</kbd>, I get this view
[image]

How can I add fuzzy search as an option? And how can I search the message body? I couldn't find anything online